# php код в <style>

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть код где в background-image надо внедрить php код

```
<div class="1" id="1" data-content-cover-id="1"  data-content-cover-bg="1.jpg" data-content-cover-height="100vh" data-content-cover-parallax="fixed"      style="background-image:url('1.jpg');height:100vh; "></div>
```

хочу в data-content-cover-bg="1.jpg и в style="background-image:url('1.jpg')
внедрить код

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'big-thumb'); ?>
```

Когда вставляю вылезает такая ошибка

```
" data-content-cover-height="100vh" data-content-cover-parallax="fixed" style="background-image:url('тут картинка видна');height:100vh; ">
```

Но не на всю страницу

ошибка походу где то здесь

```
data-content-cover-bg="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large'); ?>"
```

Comment: `Когда вставляю вылезает такая ошибка` - какая ошибка-то? Что у вас в логе ошибок на сервере есть?

Comment: не ошибка точнее, а выводит так, вместо того чтобы картинку на весь экран вывести

Comment: Функция `get_the_post_thumbnail()` выводит **html-код** изображения, а не его адрес. То есть выведет не `путь_к_изображению.jpg`, а `<img src="путь_к_изображению.jpg">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так у вас получится :)

```
<?php 
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ));
    ?>
    <div class="1" id="1" data-content-cover-id="1"  data-content-cover-bg="<?php echo $image; ?>" data-content-cover-height="100vh" data-content-cover-parallax="fixed"      style="background-image:url(<?php echo $image; ?>);height:100vh; "></div>
```